# Can we put dependency among build steps in teamcity

Tags: msbuild, batch-file, dependencies, teamcity

In Project Configuration steps, is it possible to add a dependency among build steps. For instance I have 4 build steps added. running web configs of particular project before building the project and also doing a backup before publishing a site. I want to know if one of the build step fails then it should not run the remaining build steps. How can we acheive this.

```
step 1. Using command line : to copy and compress site before publish (if this step fails it should not run the remaining steps
step 2. using msbuild: Build project before publish
step 3. using command line : Publish project
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In TeamCity build steps can only be executed sequentially. If one of build steps returns non zero exit code, TeamCity won't execute subsequent steps. Related issues from our tracker:

- http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-17939
- http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-13682